# Java skipping Console.nextLine()

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

I'm making a simple program in Java, in which ask the user:

- initialBalance, double
- rate, integer
- client, String

I have a problem: the first two inputs work, but I cannot make the third to function, the program seems to skip it.

This is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class DoublingTime{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Initial sum: ");
        final double initialBalance = console.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Interest rate: ");
        final int rate = console.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Client name: ");
        final String client = console.nextLine();
        
        double balance = initialBalance;
        int year = 0;

        while(balance < 2 * initialBalance){
            balance = balance + balance * rate / 100;
            year++;
        }

        System.out.println("To double the investment of " + client + " (interest rate of " + rate + "%) " + year + " years are needed.");

        console.close();
    }
}
```

And this is what I get on my GUI:

> Initial sum: 10000
> Interest rate: 1
> Client name: To double the investment of  (interest rate of 1%) 70 years are needed.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you use `console.nextInt();` or `console.nextDouble();` it only takes the next number, and does not consume the rest of the line. So before you attempt to get the next line with `client = console.nextLine();` you need to consume the rest of the previous line with a blank call `console.nextLine();` that assigns the input to nothing.

Comment: Use console.next() to read the next line from the console.